# Phonegap - UrbanAirship - Blackberry Mobile Push Notifications

Tags: phonegap-plugins

We've been very happy with UrbanAirship on iOS and Android but not on Blackberry.  After spending over 100 hours and blowing our estimates we have been unable to get UrbanAirship to work with Phonegap on the Blackberry.

Using Eclipse, BlackBerry webworks SDK, and Phonegap 1.0 (can't use > 1.0 on BB).  We got the information from UA’s sample app (https://github.com/urbanairship/bb-push-sample-os5) for the push integration.  Then the Phonegap plugin from here (http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/35799737/How To Create a PhoneGap Plugin for BlackBerry WebWorks).

The UA sample code was distilled down to what was needed (eliminate special UI, temporary storage, etc) and then shoehorned into the Phonegap plugin structure.  Had success calling the plugin from our javascript files (in doing so executing methods in the java plugin, and those hitting the BB core).  Failure comes trying to get the plugin to act as an event listener for push notifications.

UrbanAirship has been great in helping us out but is unwilling/unable to provide a Phonegap plugin that works with BlackBerry.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What did you guys end up doing?